# Compute the first two digits of the prime $2^{32582657}-1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have an exercise from a student to compute the first two digits of the largest (till 2008) prime number known:

$$2^{32582657}-1$$

How would I solve this exercise?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Think scientific notation.  How precisely can you compute $\log_{10}2$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Thank your for your comment. I had a blackout when tutoring, and just thought damn what a large prime.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Yes I was tutoring this student. :-) It reads a little bit strange.

Comment: Two digits in base 10, right? In binary base all the digits are 1.

Comment: If you compute $\ln 2$ and $\ln 5$ to sufficient accuracy then you can compute $x=2^{32582657}=10^A\cdot 10^B$ with $2<A\in \Bbb N$ and $1<B<2,$ and if $B$ is computed accurately enough then $\lfloor 10^B \rfloor$ is the 1st two digits of $x,$ and is also the 1st two digits of $ x-1$ because $x>100$ and the last digit of $x$ cannot be $0$ .

Comment: (i). $\ln 10 -3\ln 2=$ $\ln (1+1/9)-\ln (1-1/9)=$ $(2/9)(1+9^{-2}/3+9^{-4}/5+...).$ (ii). $10\ln 2 -3\ln 10=$ $\ln 1.024=$ $0.024-(0.024)^2/2+(0.024)^3/3-...\quad$ From (i) & (ii) we deduce $\ln 2$ and $\ln 10$ and hence obtain $\log_{10}2=(\ln 2)/\ln 10.$